# What is the difference between Boolean and boolean in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

Can someone please explain the difference between **Boolean** and **boolean** in Typescript?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Uppercase `Boolean` is an object type.

Lowercase `boolean` is a primitive type.

You should always use `boolean` (the *primitive type* in your programs).
This is because, the Typescript type system **does not** force an object to its primitive type, while JavaScript **does**.

You shouldn't write:

```
function yourFunction(foo: Boolean)
```

But instead always write:

```
function yourFunction(foo: boolean)
```

For more info, see [TypeScript Lang - Everyday Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html)